# Windows 10 won't boot from any of grub entries

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I have a Dell Inspiron 7567 Gaming laptop. It has an SSD and a hard drive. Originally Windows 10 came pre-installed on the SSD.
I performed a fresh install by completely formatting the drive and installed windows 10 on hard drive(After a couple of failed attempts, UEFI and Secure boot problems).
After that I installed ubuntu 18.04 on the SSD.
I ended up using UEFI ON and Secure Boot OFF. 
After that whenever I tried to boot into windows (from GRUB or from Boot selection by pressing F12) it gave me two options to choose from on the Windows boot screen.
It was much of annoyance rather than being a problem but things were working fine.
Today I accidentally reset the BIOS settings.
After that I am unable to boot into windows.

I tried installing boot-repair in my ubuntu and running it gave me a bunch of windows options in GRUB but I am not able to boot into windows using any of them.

Here is my bootinfosummary generated by boot-repair

http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/FDxjGx9nzb/

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does Windows directly boot from UEFI boot menu? If so it just may be fast start up is on. Grub only boots working Windows. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions What settings did you change in UEFI? If you update or reset UEFI, you have to redo any changes you made previously. I keep a list.

Comment: thanks oldfred. I'm not sure what changes I did. Anyways I ended up reinstalling windows on HDD.